# Find all strings that differ with each other in at least three positions, generated by only four characters

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, numpy

I am currently learning to code in python and one of the bonus exercises to solve is the following:

```
chars=['A','B','C','D']
```

From the list of characters above, I need to generate a list of twelve four-letter strings, that differ with each other in at least three positions.The final list can possibly look like this (the list named 'result' below is not known to me. It is just an example of what the final result can look like, a list where all the strings differ in at least three positions):

```
result=['AACC','ABAB','ADBD','BAAD','BCBC','BDCA','CABB','CBCD','CCAA','CDDC','DBDA','DCCB']
```

I am not supposed to use libraries that make it easy.
I need your help to be pointed to the right direction, if I am not going there. Check my logic and what I have done so far:

1. Find all possible combinations of the four characters (with replacement) and add them to a list.
2. Fill a numpy array with the differences by position among all strings of the list named strings.
3. Convert the array to a pandas dataframe and find a way to filter it to get the 12 strings I need. (I am stuck here).

.

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

chars=['A','B','C','D']

strings=[]

for a in chars:
    for b in chars:
        for c in chars:
            for d in chars:
                string=a+b+c+d
                strings.append(string)

a=strings
b=strings

matrix=np.zeros((len(a), len(b)),dtype=int)

def dist_by_pos(string1,string2):
    counter=0
    for i,j in zip(string1,string2):
            if i!=j:
                counter=counter+1
    return counter 

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    for j in range(0,len(b)):
        matrix[i,j] = dist_by_pos(a[i], b[j])

df=pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=a, index=b)
```

I have trouble finding how to filter the dataframe to get the words I want.

Otherwise, I think I might not need to do this with numpy/pandas and maybe just try nested for loops or something else I am currently missing.

I would appreciate any pointers!

Edit1: I better explained the task at hand to avoid confusion on whether the list named 'result' is known to me or not.

Edit2: Wrote a less misleading title.

Comment: If you are *"not supposed to use libraries that make it easy"*, then I would think that numpy and pandas are not even an option.

Comment: You have four nested loops that generate all possible strings. For each string,  check the distance to all elements of the solution array. If all the distances are >= 3, then add the string to the solution. You should be able to get 16 strings that way. So you can stop when the solution length is 12.

Comment: @user3386109: Thank you so much for editing and taking the time answering my post. I will try to implement what you suggested. I initially tried something like this, without numpy, but I made a mistake somewhere and then tried with numpy. I think i can do it :)

Comment: @user3386109: I think, I have either misunderstood you or you have misunderstood me! Maybe I did not ask my question properly. The "result" array is not known to me. It is just an example of what the result I want to get can look like. The only thing I know is the four characters of the list named 'chars'. so, from just these four characters I need to identify all 12 strings that differ from each other in at least three positions.

Comment: The result array (`strings`) starts empty. The first string created is `'AAAA'`. There's nothing in the result array, so `'AAAA'` is added. The next string created is `'AAAB'`. That string is not at distance 3 from `'AAAA'`, so it's dropped. All strings are dropped until the loops reach `'ABBB'`. That *is* at distance 3 from the existing entry in the result array, so `'ABBB'` is added. Now the result array is `['AAAA', 'ABBB']`. Subsequent strings must be at distance 3 from both. In other words, you need another loop to check that each new string is distance 3 from every string in the result.

Comment: Great, I did it! How did you calculate that the strings would be 16? I found that this solution is not scalable; let's say if we increase the string length from 4 to 6 and expect let's say 106 strings that differ in at least three positions. Adding 'AAAAAA' first would give us 64 strings. To get 106 we would need to start from 'AAAAAB'. So the question is how do we find the maximum number strings that differ in at least three positions, so we get the best possible solution?

Comment: ;) I didn't calculate, I just modified your code, and ran it. As you point out, the first entry in the result array makes a difference in the number of strings that you find with the nested loop technique. I'm sure that there are better algorithms if you want the absolute maximum number of strings. Those algorithms get into some heavy math typically used in designing error detection and correction schemes.

Comment: The first entry in the array, and the order in which you search for additional entries both affect the number of strings that you will find. Ultimately, what you're looking for is a roughly uniform distribution of points in an N-dimensional space. To get a taste of that, [read about Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance). If you pursue this line of enquiry far enough, your journey will eventually lead to [finite field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field).

Comment: Great, thank you for the interesting input!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a backtracking problem. Here is one solution:

- We represent the problem state by a partial mapping from (word, position) indices to characters.
- The algorithm starts with a blank state.
- At each step, we check if the state has a conflict (two words have the same characters in two of the same positions).

  - If no, we check if the state is done (all positions filled).

    - If no, there is at least one unfilled position. Try filling it with different letters and recurse.
    - If yes, we have a solution.
  - If yes, abort the previous guess and go back (i.e. backtrack).

---

```
from copy import copy


chars=['A','B','C','D']
# in the solved state, state[i, j] == c iff c is in the j'th position of i'th word
starting_state = {
    (i, j): None
    for i in range(12)
    for j in range(4)
}


def has_conflict(state):
    'Two words agree in two or more positions.'
    return any(
        sum(state[i1,j] == state[i2,j] for j in range(4) if state[i1,j] != None) >= 2
        for i1 in range(12) for i2 in range(i1)
    )


def state_to_words(state):
    'Convert dict representaion to a list of words'
    assert not any(v is None for v in state.values())
    words = list()
    for i in range(12):
        word_letters = list()
        for j in range(4):
            word_letters.append(state[i,j])
        word = "".join(word_letters)
        words.append(word)
    return words


def backtrack(state):
    'Find valid combinations with backtracking'
    # if no two words agree in two or more positions
    if not has_conflict(state):
        # copy state
        state = copy(state)
        # see if we are in a solved state
        if all(v is not None for v in state.values()):
            yield state_to_words(state)
            return
        # otherwise, find an empty position
        i, j = next(k for k, v in state.items() if v is None)
        # and try each letter in turn
        for c in chars:
            state[i,j] = c
            # yield from recursive call
            yield from backtrack(state)



for i, sol in enumerate(backtrack(starting_state)):
    if i > 9:
        break

    print(f"{i}: {', '.join(sol)}")

# 0: AAAA, ABBB, ACCC, ADDD, BABC, BBAD, BCDA, BDCB, CACD, CBDC, CCAB, CDBA
# 1: AAAA, ABBB, ACCC, ADDD, BABC, BBAD, BCDA, BDCB, CACD, CBDC, CCAB, DADB
# 2: AAAA, ABBB, ACCC, ADDD, BABC, BBAD, BCDA, BDCB, CACD, CBDC, CCAB, DBCA
# 3: AAAA, ABBB, ACCC, ADDD, BABC, BBAD, BCDA, BDCB, CACD, CBDC, CCAB, DCBD
# 4: AAAA, ABBB, ACCC, ADDD, BABC, BBAD, BCDA, BDCB, CACD, CBDC, CCAB, DDAC
# 5: AAAA, ABBB, ACCC, ADDD, BABC, BBAD, BCDA, BDCB, CACD, CBDC, CCAB, DDBA
# 6: AAAA, ABBB, ACCC, ADDD, BABC, BBAD, BCDA, BDCB, CACD, CBDC, CDBA, CCAB
# 7: AAAA, ABBB, ACCC, ADDD, BABC, BBAD, BCDA, BDCB, CACD, CBDC, CDBA, DADB
# 8: AAAA, ABBB, ACCC, ADDD, BABC, BBAD, BCDA, BDCB, CACD, CBDC, CDBA, DBCA
# 9: AAAA, ABBB, ACCC, ADDD, BABC, BBAD, BCDA, BDCB, CACD, CBDC, CDBA, DCAB
```